# Height of ViewController is not being set correctly

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I just don't get the setting of my view controller right. I have a ViewController implemented into another ViewController like this:

**PARENT VIEWCONTROLLER:**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self addTopTabBarController];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addTopTabBarController {
    self.topTapController = [[TopBarViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:self.topTapController];
    [self.topTapController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.topTapController.view];
    self.topTapController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 40);
}
```

**CHILD VIEWCONTROLLER**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        // Setup toolbar an set frame
        self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.size.height);

    }
    return self;
}
```

When I log the frame.size.height, I get 568.0 as return value. Why don't I get returned the 40 as being set in the parent ViewController before? Did I returned the wrong property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NSLog` in the `viewWillAppear` method.

You only get the dimensions of the view at `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Now it worked! Why is it the case that I only get the correct dimensions there?

Comment: Are you calling [super viewWillAppear:animated]; in the viewWillAppear method?

Comment: The only possible way to get the frame at the init method is to either pass it in eg `initWithFrame:(CGRect) rect{ };`. Only at `viewWillAppear` has the app worked out where everything should be and what size itself is.